# How to select two parent and one child from 2 different table

Tags: sql, join

```
CREATE TABLE PEOPLE
( 
    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "GENDER" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)

CREATE TABLE RELATIONS
( 
    "C_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "P_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE
)

INSERT INTO PEOPLE (ID, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (107, 'DAYS', 'F');
INSERT INTO PEOPLE (ID, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (145, 'HB', 'M');
INSERT INTO PEOPLE (ID, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (155, 'HANSEL', 'F');
INSERT INTO PEOPLE (ID, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (202, 'BLACKSTON', 'M');
INSERT INTO PEOPLE (ID, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (227, 'CRISS', 'F');
INSERT INTO PEOPLE (ID, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (278, 'KEFFER', 'M');
INSERT INTO PEOPLE (ID, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (305, 'CANTY', 'F');
INSERT INTO PEOPLE (ID, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (329, 'MOZINGO', 'F');
INSERT INTO PEOPLE (ID, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (425, 'NOLF', 'F');
INSERT INTO PEOPLE (ID, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (534, 'WAUGH', 'F');
INSERT INTO PEOPLE (ID, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (586, 'TONG', 'F');
INSERT INTO PEOPLE (ID, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (618, 'dimmi', 'F');
INSERT INTO PEOPLE (ID, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (747, 'BEANE', 'F');
INSERT INTO PEOPLE (ID, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (878, 'CHATMON', 'F');
INSERT INTO PEOPLE (ID, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (904, 'HANSARD', 'F');


INSERT INTO RELATIONS (C_ID, P_ID) VALUES (145, 202);
INSERT INTO RELATIONS (C_ID, P_ID) VALUES (145, 107);
INSERT INTO RELATIONS (C_ID, P_ID) VALUES (278, 305);
INSERT INTO RELATIONS (C_ID, P_ID) VALUES (278, 155);
INSERT INTO RELATIONS (C_ID, P_ID) VALUES (329, 227);
INSERT INTO RELATIONS (C_ID, P_ID) VALUES (534, 586);
INSERT INTO RELATIONS (C_ID, P_ID) VALUES (534, 878);
INSERT INTO RELATIONS (C_ID, P_ID) VALUES (618, 747);
INSERT INTO RELATIONS (C_ID, P_ID) VALUES (618, 904);
INSERT INTO RELATIONS (C_ID, P_ID) VALUES (329, 425);
```

Expected output (NOTE: child, father and mother are aliases)

```
child   father    mother
------------------------
dimmi   beane     hansard
HB      blackston days
keffer  canty     hansel
mozingo nolf      criss
waugh   tong      chatmon
```

Comment: If we presume that "father" means "male", how is - in your expected output - **Beane** (whose gender is "F") - stated as Dimmi's father? Dimmi's parents are Beand and Hansard, both females. Is that OK? (it is for me, I don't have a problem if someone has parents whose genders are equal, just asking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same gender couples -- that makes this an interesting problem.

```
select child,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then pp.name end) as mother,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then pp.name end) as father
from (select pc.name as child, pp.gender, pp.name,
             row_number() over (partition by r.c_id order by pp.gender) as seqnum
      from relations r join
           people pc
           on r.c_id = p.id join
           people pp
           on r.p_id = p2.id
     ) x
group by child;
```

Note that you can get the genders of the parents using similar logic:

```
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then pp.gender end) as mother_gender,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then pp.gender end) as father_gender
```

Of course, you might just call the parents `parent1` and `parent2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this

```
select p.name as child
       ,max(case when p2.gender='F' then p2.name end) as mother
       ,max(case when p2.gender='M' then p2.name end) as father
  from relations r
  join people p
    on r.c_id=p.id
  join people p2
    on r.p_id=p2.id
group by p.name
```

Comment: select p.name as child
       ,max(case when p2.gender='F' then p2.name end) as mother
       ,max(case when p2.gender='M' then p2.name end) as father
  from relations r
  join people p
    on r.c_id=p.id
  join people p2
    on r.p_id=p2.p_id -- here p_id col is not present in the table

Comment: I have updated now

Comment: The output is still not similar to excepted.                                                          child       father mother
HB          BLACKSTON  DAYS
WAUGH       null          TONG
dimmi       null         HANSARD
KEFFER       null          HANSEL
MOZING        null           NOLF

Comment: read the comment by LIttlefoot, if you have parents of te same gender what is the business logic for determining the father, and the logic for determining the mother